# How big should an oil leak be to make engine removal worth it?

Tags: honda, civic, oil-leak

[image]

I have a 2015 Honda Civic that has a tiny oil leak between the engine and transmission. The powertrain warranty will be expiring in 500 miles, and I was thinking that the leak maybe from the rear main seal. If so, would it be reasonable to expect thee dealership to pull out the engine and replace the seal for this tiny leak? I mean a leak is a leak, and the leak could only get worse, so why not fix it? One potential reason not to pull the engine out would be that bolts could be over tightened and mistakes could be made during removal and reinstallation. One example of this is how a dealership stripped my alternator Bolt without telling me on and older Civic.

Comment: Is that the extent of the leak? How much oil do you have to add over how many miles (i.e. 1 quart every 1,000 miles) to maintain full level?

Comment: I have a feeling any answer for this question will be fraught with opinion ... that said, here's my opinion: The vehicle is under warranty. Take it in and get it fixed. Depending on what *exactly* is wrong with the engine, there may be something bigger here which needs to be taken care of. It's better to do it on Honda's dime than on yours. That's what a warranty is for in the first place. Doesn't matter if there's 50k miles left on it or 5 ... it's still their warranty. Honda will still need to fix it. Don't feel bad for them or anything, it's what they offer and what you've paid for.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts. I'm not sure how to phrase the question to make answers non opinion based. Now the car is in the shop, I have to see what they say, and I have to think of a response.

Comment: Is the leak motor oil or transmission oil ? As you say it may be rear main on the engine , but it might be the front seal of the transmission.

Comment: It appears to be engine oil to me, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can have them check the torque on the flange bolts before anything is removed. May have not been torqued right. Leaks seem to only get worse over time so I would either have them fix it now or give you in writing a promise to fix it after the warrant expires if needed. Careful you aren't in the middle of the highway or nowhere when the leak gets worse and your oil light goes on.